Почему flexbox сразу имеет свойство space-evenly?


* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 2px solid #000
}

header {
    display: flex;
    height: 96px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background: #fff;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>#ЧИНИМ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <img src="logo header.svg" alt="Логотип" id="header_logo">
            <span id="header_text_container">
                <span class="header_text">Преимущества</span>
                <span class="header_text">Поломки</span>
                <span class="header_text">Команда</span>
                <span class="header_text">Работы</span>
            </span>
            <button id="header_button">Узнать стоимость</button>
    </header>
</body>
</html>



Почему в этом коде display: flex сразу принимает свойство justify-content: space-evenly?
Ведь если я напишу это свойство, то ничего не поменяется, а flexbox как я знаю, то почти ничего не меняет

Если вы уберёте margin, то увидите, что никакого space-evenly тут нет

спасибо большое
